# Google vision product search Api

Tags: laravel, google-vision

[null product error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCQNt.png)
I hope this message finds you well. I am currently working with the Google Product Search API in PHP using the Laravel framework. Unfortunately, I am encountering an issue where the product_search_results consistently returns null.

I have taken the following steps to troubleshoot the problem:

Image Format and Size:

I have verified that the image format and size are correct and within the expected parameters.
API Requests:

I have reviewed my API requests, ensuring that the necessary parameters, including the product set ID, are provided.
Error Handling:

I have implemented error handling in my code to capture any potential error messages returned by the API, but no specific issues have been identified.
Despite these efforts, I am still unable to receive valid responses, and product_search_results remains null.

this is my function where I am calling
[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L67U1.png)
this is what I am getting in response

[getting response and product search is always null in every image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Clt5k.png)

I am using google vision product search where i am uploading image and want to get the seacrh result related to that image with all details like we are getting in google lens.